# list of Page Categories on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, koala

I'm developing a facebook search and I would like to list all the page categories (is not relevant but I'm working with koala ruby gem):

A search with type="page" has results like these:

```
{"category"=>"Community", "name"=>"Koala", "id"=>"7356642860"}
{"category"=>"Product/service", "name"=>"Koala Groupe", "id"=>"188919981197745"}
{"category"=>"Public figure", "name"=>"Cushelle Koala", "id"=>"109202405786555"}
{"category"=>"Dancer", "name"=>"Koala Dance Bots", "id"=>"208563099183596"}
{"category"=>"Musician/band", "name"=>"Kid Koala", "id"=>"17527901121"}
{...}
```

I'm trying to develop a form to permit the user to achieve a a more precise search.

Then, I would like the user to have a **list of categories**, but: How to get the facebook pages categories list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question here:

[Authoritative List of all Facebook Subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488834/authoritative-list-of-all-facebook-subcategories/18496526#18496526)

that I responded to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following API to get list of page categories

```
FB.api(
  '/fb_page_categories',
  'GET',
  {},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
You will get response as
 {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Advertising/Marketing",
        "fb_page_categories": [
          {
            "name": "Advertising Agency",
            "id": "164886566892249"
          },
          {
            "name": "Brand Agency",
            "id": "1736039333278498"
          },
          {
            "name": "Copywriting Service",
            "id": "197029287003787"
          },
          {
            "name": "Digital/Online Marketing Agency",
            "id": "1751954525061797"
          },
          {
            "name": "Internet Marketing Service",
            "id": "1706730532910578"
          },
          {
            "name": "Marketing Agency",
            "id": "123377808095874"
          },
          {
            "name": "Marketing Consultant",
            "id": "170992992946914"
          },
          {
            "name": "Media Agency",
            "id": "281507032196735"
          },
          {
            "name": "Public Relations Agency",
            "id": "192021210817573"
          },
          {
            "name": "Social Media Agency",
            "id": "530553733821238"
          },
          {
            "name": "Telemarketing Service",
            "id": "197557456921449"
          }
        ],
        "id": "1757592557789532"
      }

and so on....
```

Answer (score 1):

A standard Graph API call would be:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/fb_page_categories?access_token={access_token_obfuscated}`