# Authoritative List of all Facebook Subcategories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know of any way to programmatically list all Facebook subcategories for places? I've seen this list here in another post which lists all categories (not subcategories), which is the same listed in the source code on the Facebook company creation page: [Facebook Pages — Authoritative List of Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216648/facebook-pages-authoritative-list-of-categories)

I'd like to categorize some businesses on Facebook so that they're easier to digest, but it seems that half of all businesses pick the category "local business" under "local business or place." Not really helpful to have the majority of all businesses in one catch all bucket.

Here's an example of a place categorized as local business with a subcategory of bar. Would be really helpful to get a full list of the subcategories. Thanks for the help.

```
{
      "page_id": xxxxx, 
      "description": "", 
      "name": "xxxxx Lounge", 
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 110290705711626, 
          "name": "Bar"
        }
      ], 
      "pic_big": "xxxxx.png", 
      "type": "LOCAL BUSINESS"
    },
```

Answer (score 10):

Facebook just made some changes to their graph API. The list of all subcategories (which Facebook calls "place topics") can be viewed in the Graph API Explorer here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplacetopic%26topic_filter%3Dall%26fields%3Did%2Cname%2Cparent_ids

The API call itself is:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all&fields=id,name,parent_ids&access_token=

It has the full taxonomy in that all topics list their parent topics, but if you wanted a bidirectional relationship, you would have to reverse engineer it yourself.

To avoid confusion it might be worth noting that what Facebook calls "Categories" is a higher level breakdown of page categorization. Each page can only have on Category, so there isn't any built in taxonomy, but they can have many Page Topics. I'm not sure where or if the full list is online, but it's this (Sorry for the ugly; I had some formatting issues):

### Categories requiring location info:

category   category_enum                               Description

1111    MOVIE_THEATER                    Movie Theater

1209    CONCERT_VENUE                    Concert Venue

1305    BOOK_STORE                                 Book Store

1306    LIBRARY                          Library

1607    LAWYER                           Lawyer

1608    DOCTOR                           Doctor

1900    RESTAURANT_CAFE                  Restaurant/Cafe

2100    BAR                              Bar

2101    CLUB                             Club

2231    SPORTS_OUTDOORS                  Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods

2500    LOCAL                            Local Business

2501    HOTEL                            Hotel

2506    AIRPORT                          Airport

2507    SPORTS_VENUE                     Sports Venue

2508    ARTS_ENTERTAINMENT               Arts/Entertainment/Nightlife

2509    AUTOMOTIVE                       Automotive

2510    SPA_BEAUTY                       Spas/Beauty/Personal Care

2511    EVENT_PLANNING                   Event Planning/Event Services

2512    BANKS                            Bank/Financial Services

2513    FOOD_GROCERY                     Food/Grocery

2514    HEALTH_MEDICAL                   Health/Medical/Pharmacy

2515    HOME_IMPROVEMENT                 Home Improvement

2516    PET_SERVICES                     Pet Services

2517    PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES            Professional Services

2518    BUSINESS_SERVICES                Business Services

2519    COMMUNITY_GOVERNMENT             Community/Government

2520    REAL_ESTATE                      Real Estate

2521    SHOPPING_RETAIL                  Shopping/Retail

2524    SPORTS_RECREATION                Sports/Recreation/Activities

2525    TOURS_SIGHTSEEING                Tours/Sightseeing

2526    TRANSPORTATION_TOURISM           Transportation

2527    HOSPITAL_CLINIC                  Hospital/Clinic

2528    MUSEUM                           Museum/Art Gallery

### Categories not requiring location info:

category   category_enum                 Description

1201    SONG                            Song

1200    ALBUM                           Album

1202    MUSICIAN_BAND                   Musician/Band

1204    MUSIC_INSTRUMENT        Musical Instrument

1206    PLAYLIST                        Playlist

1207    MUSIC_VIDEO             Music Video

1208    CONCERT_TOUR                    Concert Tour

1210    RADIO_STATION                   Radio Station

1211    RECORD_LABEL                    Record Label

1212    MUSIC_AWARD             Music Award

1213    MUSIC_CHART             Music Chart

1105    MOVIE                           Movie

1103    ACTOR_DIRECTOR                  Actor/Director

1108    PRODUCER                        Producer

1109    MOVIE_WRITER                    Writer

1110    MOVIE_STUDIO                    Studio

1112    TV_MOVIE_AWARD                  TV/Movie Award

1113    FICTIONAL_CHARACTER      Fictional Character

1400    TV_SHOW                         TV Show

1402    TV_NETWORK              TV Network

1404    TV_CHANNEL              TV Channel

1405    EPISODE                         Episode

1300    BOOK                                    Book

1301    AUTHOR                          Author

1304    PUBLISHER                       Publisher

1308    EDITOR                          Editor

1307    MAGAZINE                        Magazine

1600    ATHLETE                         Athlete

1700    POLITICIAN              Politician

1601    ARTIST                          Artist

1701    GOVERNMENT_OFFICIAL      Government Official

1602    PERSON                          Public Figure

1605    NEWS_PERSONALITY        News Personality

1604    JOURNALIST              Journalist

1606    CHEF                                    Chef

1609    BUSINESS_PERSON                 Business Person

1610    COMEDIAN                        Comedian

1611    ENTERTAINER             Entertainer

1612    MONARCH                         Monarch

1613    TEACHER                         Teacher

1614    DANCER                          Dancer

1901    CUISINE                         Cuisine

2000    FOOD                                    Food

2001    DRINK                           Drink

2202    WEBSITE                         Website

2205    CAR                             Cars

2206    BAGS_LUGGAGE                    Bags/Luggage

2208    CAMERA_PHOTO                    Camera/Photo

2209    CLOTHING                        Clothing

2210    COMPUTER                        Computers

2211    SOFTWARE                        Software

2212    OFFICE_SUPPLIES                 Office Supplies

2213    ELECTRONICS             Electronics

2215    APPLIANCES              Appliances

2216    BUILDING_MATS                   Building Materials

2217    COMMERCIAL_EQUIPMENT     Commercial Equipment

2218    HOME_DECOR              Home Decor

2219    FURNITURE                       Furniture

2220    HOUSEHOLD_SUPPLIES      Household Supplies

2221    KITCHEN_SUPPLIES        Kitchen/Cooking

2222    PATIO_GARDEN                    Patio/Garden

2223    TOOLS_EQUIPMENT                 Tools/Equipment

2224    WINE_SPIRITS                    Wine/Spirits

2226    JEWELRY_WATCHES                 Jewelry/Watches

2227    MOVIES_MUSIC                    Movies/Music

2230    PET_SUPPLIES                    Pet Supplies

2232    BABY_KIDS                       Baby Goods/Kids Goods

2262    VITAMIN_SUPPLEMENTS      Vitamins/Supplements

2263    DRUGS                           Drugs

2201    PRODUCT_SERVICE                 Product/Service

2300    GAME                                    Games/Toys

2301    APP                             App Page

2505    TRANSIT_STOP                    Transit Stop

2523    ATTRACTIONS             Attractions/Things to Do

2503    LANDMARK                        Landmark

2522    PARKS_POI                       Public Places

2200    COMPANY                         Company

2233    MEDIA_NEWS_COMPANY      Media/News/Publishing

2234    BANK_FINANCIAL_COMPANY   Bank/Financial Institution

2235    NGO                             Non-Governmental Organization (NGO)

2236    INSURANCE_COMPANY       Insurance Company

2237    SMALL_BUSINESS                  Small Business

2238    ENERGY_COMPANY                  Energy/Utility

2239    RETAIL_COMPANY                  Retail and Consumer Merchandise

2240    AUTO_COMPANY                    Automobiles and Parts

2241    INDUSTRIALS_COMPANY     Industrials

2242    TRANSPORT_FREIGHT       Transport/Freight

2243    HEALTH_COMPANY                  Health/Medical/Pharmaceuticals

2214    HEALTH_BEAUTY                   Health/Beauty

2244    AEROSPACE_COMPANY       Aerospace/Defense

2245    MINING_COMPANY                  Mining/Materials

2246    FARMING_COMPANY                 Farming/Agriculture

2247    CHEMICAL_COMPANY        Chemicals

2248    CONSULTING_COMPANY      Consulting/Business Services

2249    LEGAL_COMPANY                   Legal/Law

2250    EDUCATION_COMPANY       Education

2251    ENGINEERING_COMPANY      Engineering/Construction

2252    FOOD_COMPANY                    Food/Beverages

2253    TELECOM                         Telecommunication

2254    BIOTECH_COMPANY                 Biotechnology

2255    COMPUTER_COMPANY        Computers/Technology

2256    INTERNET_COMPANY                Internet/Software

2258    TRAVEL_COMPANY                  Travel/Leisure

2260    COMMUNITY_ORG                   Community Organization

2261    POLITICAL_ORG                   Political Organization

2264    RELIGIOUS_ORG                   Church/Religious Organization

2600    ORG_GENERAL             Organization

2601    SCHOOL                          School

2602    UNIVERSITY              University

2604    GOVERNMENT_ORG                  Government Organization

2603    NON_PROFIT              Non-Profit Organization

2606    CAUSE                           Cause

2618    POLITICAL_PARTY                 Political Party

2612    COMMUNITY                       Community

1800    SPORTS_LEAGUE                   Sports League

1801    SPORTS_TEAM             Professional Sports Team

1802    COACH                           Coach

1803    AMATEUR_TEAM                    Amateur Sports Team

1804    SCHOOL_TEAM             School Sports Team

2700    PERSONAL_BLOG                   Personal Blog

2701    ARTS_SITE                       Arts/Humanities Website

2702    BIZ_SITE                        Business/Economy Website

2703    COMPUTER_SITE                   Computers/Internet Website

2704    EDU_SITE                        Education Website

2705    ENTERTAINMENT_SITE      Entertainment Website

2706    GOV_SITE                        Government Website

2707    HEALTH_SITE             Health/Wellness Website

2708    HOME_SITE                       Home/Garden Website

2709    NEWS_SITE                       News/Media Website

2710    REC_SITE                        Recreation/Sports Website

2711    REF_SITE                        Reference Website

2712    REGIONAL_SITE                   Regional Website

2713    SCIENCE_SITE                    Science Website

2714    SOCIETY_SITE                    Society/Culture Website

2715    TRAVEL_SITE             Local/Travel Website

2716    KIDS_SITE                       Teens/Kids Website

2717    PERSONAL_SITE                   Personal Website

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Facebook doesn't offer this level of detail.

A better plan is to use [Factual](https://developer.factual.com/docs/places-overview). They publish a [full taxonomy](https://developer.factual.com/docs/places-categories#fn1), and using their Crosswalk API can cross-reference most records back to a Facebook page / place.

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely helpful. Unfortunately, the data I'm looking for is tied to events, which I'm pulling from the local businesses from Facebook. Seems the only way I can categorize them is through who is throwing the event. Guess it will be more a of brute force exercise.