# How to retrieve Page main Category

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I would like to retrieve all Facebook Page's Categories, not the sub-categories list but the main Category that we use to specify  element when creating page with Facebook Graph API.

Currently, I'm able to retrieve top subcategories either with :

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=top&fields=id,name

or

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all&fields=id,name,parent_ids

But I don't see main category in result like 2200:"Company", etc.

I'm looking for all category from id 1105 to 2618

Is it possible to get list of main category ?

Thank you,

Comment: _“Is it possible to get list of main category ?”_ – no.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18496526/561485

Comment: I know how to get subcategories, but I'm looking to get list of main Page category by the API not from forum or other source.