# Facebook Graph API : possible values for category and categories_list fields of a place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has not provided with any list of possible values for these fields.

[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search) They have stated some categories for searching but these are not the values that are returned, Instead following values are returned for every place. I'm okay with that but where do I get a list of possible values for fields category and categories_list.

Thank you very much.

```js
{
      "checkins": 78,
      "name": "SODA SHOTS & CAFE",
      "location": {
        "city": "Sangli",
        "country": "India",
        "latitude": 16.85507,
        "longitude": 74.59768,
        "street": "SIDE GATE OF WILLINGDON COLLEGE,NEAR BANK OF MAHARASTRA ,JAYHIND COLONY ,VISHRAMBAGH",
        "zip": "416416"
      },
      "category": "Coffee Shop",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "128673187201735",
          "name": "Coffee Shop"
        },
        {
          "id": "273819889375819",
          "name": "Restaurant"
        }
      ],
      "id": "246105402415302"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more searches I found an answer

[Authoritative List of all Facebook Subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488834/authoritative-list-of-all-facebook-subcategories/18496526#18496526)

I'm beginner here and don't know what do now about the thread, someone please mark this as duplicate or please take appropriate action.
Thanks, all.